# drop duplicate based on column length

Tags: python, pandas

I need to drop duplicate based on the length of the column "Employee History". The column with the longest length should be kept
Note: (there are many, many more columns, but this is the 2 columns that matter for this case)

|  | Company ID | Employee History |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 253 | 462106-27 | 2021: 21, 2022: 26 |  |  |
| 264 | 181831-33 | 2019: 20, 2020: 60, 2021: 172, 2022: 225 |  |  |
| 338 | 181831-33 | 2019: 20, 2020: 60, 2021: 172 |  |  |
| 3481 | 462106-27 | 2021: 21 |  |  |

Comment: Can you please explain your question? What do you mean by column with the longest length? Duplicates of what and length of what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sort the whole data frame by the length of `Employee History` in descending order and then drop duplicates by the subset `Company ID`. The drop methods keeps the first element, which is always linked to the longest values of `Employee History`.

Code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Company ID": ["462106-27", "181831-33", "181831-33", "462106-27"],
    "Employee History": ["2021: 21, 2022: 26", "019: 20, 2020: 60, 2021: 172, 2022: 225", "019: 20, 2020: 60, 2021: 172", "2021: 21"]}, 
     index =[253, 264, 338, 3481] 
)

df.assign(temp=df["Employee History"].str.len()).sort_values(by=["Company ID", "temp"], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=["Company ID"]).drop(columns="temp")
```

Output:

```py
      Company ID   Employee History                       
253   462106-27    2021: 21, 2022: 26                         
264   181831-33    019: 20, 2020: 60, 2021: 172, 2022: 22
```

Answer (score 2):

Below solution drops duplicates based on Max lengh of column `Employee History` :

```
#Assign new column with String lengh.
df = df.assign(count=(df["Employee History"].str.len()))

#Drop duplicated columns based on Max lengh.
df = df.loc[df.groupby('Company ID')['count'].idxmax()].drop('count', axis=1)
```

Comment: Be cautious with the `max` function as differential criteria. If you change the data frame to: `df = pd.DataFrame({"Company ID": [462106, 181831, 181831, 462106], "Employee History": ["2021: 21, 2022: 26", "019: 20, 2020: 60, 2021: 172, 2022: 225", "019: 20, 2020: 60, 2021: 172", "2022: 21"]}, index =[253, 264, 338, 3481])` your solution doesn't hold anymore.

Comment: Your right Thanks! , i have updated my solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, sort the data set by the length of "Employee History". Then insert every row into a OrderedDict using the "Company ID" as key and other columns as value. Finally, restore the dict to table.

Note: from python 3.7, regular dicts are guaranteed to be ordered, too.